# How is it possible storage hard disk failure cause system disk to fail to read/write?

Tags: server, hard-drive, filesystem, hardware

Update:
One of the 3TB Seagate Storage Drives was dying and any time I had it connected to the system, I got the IO/read errors, eventually even when the system was booting.

As described below, booting to an old kernel gave me several hours of reliable service so that I could do a backup of the most recent data on drive, and now it is inaccessible by any system I hook it into. It's backed up, so no worries there.

Nothing about the scenario makes a lot of sense, because removing a storage drive (not the system disk) seems to have fixed all issues. Why would a dying drive behave this way? I think it was dumb luck that booting into older kernel gave me good results.

Can anyone explain how this storage drive failure caused all of these problems?

Have I inadvertently solved a different problem?

---

> We have an old Dell Optiplex running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a file and
>   ftp server for the company. I had done updates and it had appeared to
>   be running without problems on newly installed software from apt and
>   new kernels, etc. The machine wasn't even rebooted since last night,
>   but this morning it's had this host of problems:
>
> 1. Connecting over SSH works but `ls` gave me an IO error before reboot.
> 2. Rebooting/shutdown now makes the machine get stuck. Error is `rpcbind: rpcbind terminating on signal.`
> 3. After a hard reboot, usb keyboard seems to be sending incorrect information to PC, as my password doesn't appear to work when I log
>      in, but SSH works as expected, with or without SSH keys.
> 4. In newer versions of kernels, I cannot `less` most files, although after a reboot `ls` works and I can open all directories without a lot
>      of trouble.
> 5. In newer kernels, SMB and Netatalk can connect but the machines give generic "permissions" or other random errors to say they can't
>      open files that they can see.
> 6. I have booted to `3.8.0-29-generic` and these problems seem resolved, but this is like putting on a spare tire.
>
> I have run the hardware diagnostic with no warnings, so I don't think
>   there are problems with the PC hardware, mobo, SATA cables, HDD, etc.
>   It appears to be a software problem since the older kernel seems to
>   "fix" the issue, but I'm not ruling out intermittent hardware failure.